# Sending SOAP messages Using KSOAP2 With Android

Tags: java, android, web-services, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

Hi I'm trying to use KSOAP2 2.6.2 android assembly to connect to a java WebService deployed on glassfish 3.1.1. from my android program.
Here are my Namespaces

```
public static final String SERVICE_NAMESPACE = "za.co.n7.mobilebackup";
public static final String SERVICE_URL = "http://ipaddress:8080/MobileBackupServiceImplService/MobileBackupServiceImpl/";
```

Here is My Send Method

```
    final String METHOD_NAME = "Login";
    SoapObject results = null;
    SoapObject request = null;
    HttpTransportSE loginHttpTransport = null;
    try {
        request = new SoapObject(MBUtil.SERVICE_NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("username", username);
        request.addProperty("password", MBUtil.hashPassword(password));

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.bodyOut=request;
        envelope.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
        envelope.env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";

        // Web method call
        loginHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(MBUtil.SERVICE_URL);
        loginHttpTransport.debug = true;
        loginHttpTransport.call(MBUtil.SERVICE_URL + METHOD_NAME, envelope);

        results = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

        System.out.println("Received Result without issue");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(loginHttpTransport.requestDump);
        System.out.println(loginHttpTransport.responseDump);
    } finally {
        finish();
    }
```

And I'm getting the following Error in the DDMS LogCat.

```
04-08 15:30:42.508: W/System.err(1454): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:END_DOCUMENT null@1:0 in   java.io.InputStreamReader@4056c7a8) 
04-08 15:30:42.508: W/System.err(1454):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.exception(KXmlParser.java:273)
04-08 15:30:42.508: W/System.err(1454):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextTag(KXmlParser.java:1413)
04-08 15:30:42.508: W/System.err(1454):     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:126)
04-08 15:30:42.508: W/System.err(1454):     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:100)
04-08 15:30:42.519: W/System.err(1454):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:195)
04-08 15:30:42.519: W/System.err(1454):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
04-08 15:30:42.519: W/System.err(1454):     at za.co.n7.mobilebackup.LoginActivity.connect(LoginActivity.java:149)
04-08 15:30:42.519: W/System.err(1454):     at za.co.n7.mobilebackup.LoginActivity$DoLoginRequest.run(LoginActivity.java:116)
04-08 15:30:42.519: W/System.err(1454):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-08 15:30:42.519: W/System.err(1454):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-08 15:30:42.519: W/System.err(1454):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-08 15:30:42.519: W/System.err(1454):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-08 15:30:42.519: W/System.err(1454):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 15:30:42.519: W/System.err(1454):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-08 15:30:42.519: W/System.err(1454):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-08 15:30:42.528: W/System.err(1454):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-08 15:30:42.528: W/System.err(1454):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've copied my SOAP Message and pasted it in soapUI and It gets a result. can anyone assist me, i've been struggling with this for hours now. 
Here is the sample of my SOAP Message

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <v:Header/>
  <v:Body>
      <n0:Login id="o0" c:root="1" xmlns:n0="za.co.n7.mobilebackup">
         <username i:type="d:string">umohduke</username>
         <password i:type="d:string">c4066ed69b81d6b2b25f76405195c83ddaeecd8dbd3866f17912b895a72bc059</password>
      </n0:Login>
   </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just try this method :

**Sending file to web server using Android.**

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
try {
    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(image);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
}

bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fileInputStream);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
IMAGE= Base64.encodeBytes(data);
Log.e("THE IMAGE BYTES",""+IMAGE);
```

Image is String to send to web server.

Source : [aruljack's blog (mine)](http://aruljack.blogspot.in/2012/08/its-ksoap-codes-to-send-image-and-file.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but try this:

```
public static final String SERVICE_NAMESPACE = "http://za.co.n7.mobilebackup";
```

instead of

```
public static final String SERVICE_NAMESPACE = "za.co.n7.mobilebackup";
```

Comment: Are you using `10.0.2.2` as ip address?

Comment: nope, nevermind I decided to use icesoap. Thats working for me now.